# Cannot change drive letter in command prompt (cmd) other than C:\

Tags: windows-10

Not sure what might have triggered this but I have noticed that while using the command prompt in windows 10 I am unable to change the drive using the `cd` command for any of the drive letters other than C:. I have also noticed that the autocomplete function works just fine when trying to change directory into a specific folder from the target drive but the change in the directory just doesn't happen.

Screenshots of the Disk Management tool and actual cmd prompt commands will follow:

[Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpGQM.png)

[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6thqk.png)

This behavior does not apply to PowerShell so I can successfully change the drives.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's normal. For historical reasons, that's just how the *cd* command works in Cmd.exe, because that's how it worked in MS-DOS COMMAND.COM as well. The directory change *is* remembered (Cmd tracks it per-drive, as did MS-DOS), but you have to switch the actual drive separately – by typing just the drive:

```
C:\>  e:
E:\>  cd \fonts
E:\Fonts>  _
```

The opposite would also work even though it would be very un-obvious:

```
C:\>  cd e:\fonts
C:\>  e:
E:\Fonts>  _
```

(And note that when you use e.g. `cd e:` in your screenshot, this doesn't *change* anything, rather it *shows* you the current directory for that drive letter.)

However, Cmd.exe has a shortcut for changing both – the `/d` option makes *cd* work sanely:

```
cd /d e:\fonts
```

The *pushd/popd* commands do not require amything extra, as they weren't present in MS-DOS and aren't burdened with compatibility. (I used to use *doskey* aliases `[=pushd $*` and `]=popd` a lot.)

```
pushd e:\fonts
...
popd
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning pushd / popd as these work for network drives

Comment: So you are telling me that after using windows for more than 20 years it's the first time I needed to change the drive and I've always needed to use /d in order to accomplish that?

Comment: @Isaz: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 7):

cd [drive]:\directory will change the current directory “context” on that drive but won’t change to that drive itself.

If you subsequently just type [drive]:, it’ll change to that drive and remember the directory you previously “cd”’ed into.

CMD has always behaved like this.

PowerShell’s “cd” is an alias to Set-Location, which always changes the current drive as well as directory.

Answer (score 4):

Just type the drive letter

```
C:\Users>K:
```